# Linear and Angular kinematics for vehicle attitude and position estimation

Tags: classical-mechanics, kinematics, vectors, inertial-frames, rotational-kinematics

I am building a robotics college level project, an unmanned aerial vehicle or a drone.
I am using a mpu 6050 IMU for getting instantaneous acceleration and angular velocity of the system.
I will be using dead reckoning for position and attitude estimation.

I wanted to verify if the angular and linear kinematics formula will work here for orientataion and position estimation and prediction

**There is 2 main goal of this project**

1. Estimate the current position and orientation of the UGV
2. Predict the future position and orientation of the UGV

For this I have researched online and I have found out possibly linear kinematics and angular kinematics formula may work for the prediction and estimation part
Below are the kinematics formula

**Linear Kinematics**

[image]

**Angular Kinematics**

[image]

**Question**

1. I wanted to determine if these formula will work for obtaining estimated and predicted position in 3D co-ordinate system or in vector form, can i obtain position(predicted or estimated) in x,y,z axis separately with the use of the linear kinematics formula and similarly for angular kinematics formula. Like in the below picture,
   [image]
2. Are the above formula correct, will they work for an uav application. I wanted to know if individual component of unbalanced acceleration on each axis of the system will affect the calculations in another axis, suppose there is a ax as well as ay component acceleration action upon the drone will the acceleration on y axis affect or counter the acceleration on x axis and the calculations involved will be changed ?